# SwiftUI - Use veryShortWeekdaySymbols in European Format

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, localization, calendar

I am working on a new project with Xcode 13 using Swift UI.

[image]

Until now when I entered Italian in Xcode, on my real device I was able to read in Italian the weekdays the language obtained through the use of `calendar.veryShortWeekdaySymbols`.

```
struct MonthView<DateView>: View where DateView: View {
    @Environment(\.calendar) var calendar
    var body: some View {
     
        ForEach(calendar.veryShortWeekdaySymbols, id: \.self) { weekDay in
            Text("\(weekDay)")
            etc..
        }
    }
}
```

Now even if I add the Italian language in the project when I run my app on the real device the weekdays are all English.

What I get is:

> S | M | T | W | T | F | S

But I would like:

> L | M | M | G | V | S | D

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you set the language of the device to Italian? It is the device setting that rules with regard to the apps running on it.

Comment: @Yrb Yes until now I have never had any problems ... I do not know if there can be a problem with iOS 15 or I am the one who did something wrong.

On my device:
settings -> general -> language and zone

I have Italian "iPhone Language"

Comment: Does `Text(LocalizedStringKey(weekDay))` work?

Comment: @Yrb Text (LocalizedStringKey (weekDay))

it always returns me the days of the week in English format

Comment: @Yrb I want to clarify that my app must not have two languages ​​(Italian - English) but only Italian

Comment: I was looking at the docs... is your Region set to Italy? And have you set your locale? "By default, Calendars have no locale set. If you wish to receive a localized answer, be sure to set the locale property first - most likely to Locale.autoupdatingCurrent."